FYI: On the topic of the Monero StackExchange proposal:)
Just in case anyone is interested, the Monero StackExchange proposal is at the Commitment phase, and we'd appreciate and welcome any committers from the Bitcoin Stack:)
You may also note a number of new participants in the Bitcoin Stack. This is because one of the requirements of passing the commitment phase is that 100 of the committers have 200+ rep on another Stack. There has been a lot of discussion about this on IRC, and people have been linking to answers they've provided on the Bitcoin Stack, but we have been doing our best to prevent vote brigading and to encourage genuine participation.
Of course, some people have already realised that the fastest way to earn rep is to be the fastest to correctly answer a question, so you'll have to excuse us if we're trying to madly bash at the keyboard faster than everyone else here;)

I was on vacation while this happened, but what I've seen from going through the posts of the last month is that 25+ new accounts tripled total voting and doubled posts on the site for about two weeks.
The majority of those added votes went to other members of your group, and vote-brigading is an accurate description of what happened: You've by-passed our review process, completely ignored the culture of the site, and I'm afraid that most of those "new users genuinely participating" will not contribute a dot after reaching two hundred rep.
In the aftermath, we're left with a large number of posts that have upvote levels which usually only are reached by the best or most interesting content here – a few of which are great, while others are mediocre, duplicates, and off-topic. We're looking at about two or three weeks of clean-up work.
Until the Monero.SE gets up and running, feel free to add to our tag monero.

If you want the new users to hang around after they hit 200+ rep then give them reasons to, unless you want this place to end up as fractured and broken as the Bitcoin community on Reddit. Additionally, note that large swathes of the Monero community have been involved in Bitcoin for a significantly longer period of time than you, but were previously disinterested in StackExchange. Finally, it's in the interests of this Stack to build up a good relationship so that, in future, relevant questions are directed here.

Also I'd love some examples of answers that are "mediocre, duplicates, and off-topic", because in my examination I've only seen well-written, often quite long answers that are correct in the answer they give. In fact, the answers I've looked at from Monero community members have been significantly better in quality than most of the answers on this Stack.

Hello fluffyponyza, you're right, there were some good and a few great contributions there, too. But there also were a bunch of service review questions, some content that was completely unrelated to cryptocurrencies, and a lot of completely subjective topics, all of which is off-topic. Very few questions are tagged correctly (which usually happens during review). Very few posts would have gotten anywhere near as many upvotes organically as they did. I've invested hundreds of hours curating content on this site, you're in no position to call me an "entitled douchenozzle moderator".

Then the solution, given the circumstance, is to come up with a canned message you can send to all those that are flagged, encouraging them to remove their clustered votes and to instead participate on the site in a broader manner. That way you won't need to spend weeks doing clean-up, the users themselves will self-correct, and you can take action with those that have not. This reduces your moderation burden, and turns those mediocre participants into good participants.

I have some doubts that requesting people to change their past voting would have broad success, but the idea has some merit. Thank you by the way for helping us understand what was happening. I had been approached a few times since I've been back about weird upvotes, but hadn't discovered the pattern at that point yet.

@fluffyponyza The point of the normal review process is that new users are gradually onboarded, and learn the informal rules and etiquette that make the site run smoothly. If moderators are human exception handlers, what you're doing is the equivalent of On Error Resume Next. WRT fragmention: that's a very real concern. I'd like to move forward to a situation where we have a critical mass of users on the [tag:monero] tag. I don't know whether we can do that without the introduction of a new SE, but I certainly intend to try.

@murch Just found this thread. The Monero community likely has many users with a vested interest in the success of Bitcoin (probably more so than most alt coin communities). Clearly many people did build stackexchange reputation here, but I think they can be motivated to continue to participate in this Stack  going forward. We want the Monero and Bitcoin stacks exchange sites to remain on good terms.

@Murch as a follow up to my last comment I also posted on Reddit. I think  the Monero community will be willing to respond by becoming more active here. The great majority of us are Bitcoin users too https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4xi25e/remaining_on_good_terms_with_bitcoin_se_if_you/

@GameChanger Thank you for reaching out. To be honest, I was a bit too annoyed when I wrote the post above. Especially since, a few people already pop up with some answers every once in a while that came in through the Monero beta. So, I guess in the end it's alright. :)
